# Animation delay on list - Toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to create a delayed list items appearing slowly and it's done. But I need it to work as a click toggle. Right now when I click "click" button once, it will come all the list slowly, but I need to hide it on second click like a click toggle. I tried to add setTimeout and add an extra class, but no luck.

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(".ul-nav li").each(function(i, li) {
            var $list = $(this).closest('ul');
            $list.delay(130).queue(function() {
                $(li).addClass('animation-li').fadeIn(2000);
                $list.dequeue();
            });
        });
    }, 30);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0kj26v1a/

What should I do?

Comment: something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rgza0p1k/) ?

Comment: So do you want to toggle showing or not the items of the list?

Comment: You could check `if $(li).hasClass('animation-li')...` first in your click function and then hide it if it does and if not, run your animation. Admittedly @Geo's comment is obviously better.

Comment: let me post that as an answer so it would be easy to access for anyone interested

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the part where you are just adding the `animation-li` class and not removing it when clicked again. There is [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) of jQuery that you can use for that. 
This will just remove the class if added already or add otherwise.

```js
//Menu transition
$('.click').click(function() {
    $(".ul-nav li").each(function(i, li) {
        var $list = $(this).closest('ul');
        $list.delay(130).queue(function() {
            $(li).toggleClass('animation-li').fadeIn(2000);
            $list.dequeue();
        });
    });
});
```

```css
ul li{
  opacity: 0;
}

.animation-li{
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="click">Click</p>

<ul class="ul-nav">
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>abc</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

with `reverse` animation

```js
let display=true;
//Menu transition
 $('.click').click(function(){
     let li=display ? $(".ul-nav li") : $($(".ul-nav li").get().reverse());
     li.each(function(i, li) {
     var $list = $(this).closest('ul');
     $list.delay(130).queue(function() {
         $(li).toggleClass('animation-li').fadeIn(2000);
        $list.dequeue();
     });
 });
  display=!display;
});
```

```css
ul li{
  opacity: 0;
}

.animation-li{
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="click">Click</p>

<ul class="ul-nav">
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abc</li>
  <li>abc</li>
</ul>
```